# How can I read UITextField value in an IBAction. I'm creating UITextField programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

How can I read `UITextField` value in an `IBAction`? I'm creating `UITextField` programmatically. So I can't set `@property` and `@synthesize` using Xcode. The code to generate `UITextField` is as follows:

```
for(i=0; i<[fieldName count]; i++)
{
    UITextField *name = [fieldName objectAtIndex:i];
    frame = CGRectMake(fromLeft, fromTop, totalWidth, totalHeight);
    name = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    name.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    name.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    //name.placeholder = [fieldName objectAtIndex:i];
    name.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    name.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
    name.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;

    [name addTarget:self action:@selector(doneEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];   
    [scroller addSubview:name];
    fromTop = fromTop + 40;
}
```

Now I want to read values of each textbox in a button click (`IBAction`). Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this to loop through all `UITextFields` that are subviews of `self.view` and add their text to a `NSMutableArray`:

```
for (UITextField *field in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        if ([[field text] length] > 0) {
            [someMutableArray addObject:field.text];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ys i think your answer will help me. But am having those UITextField in a ScrollView `[scroller addSubview:name];`. so is that possible to call `self.view.subviews` or i need to use  `scroller.subviews` in that for loop. Also i have some other controls inside the same ScrollView. So how can i read only UITextField Values..

Comment: Sure i will mark ur answer as the correct answer :).. Also can u please tell me how can i read only UITextField Values...

Comment: Thanks for ur great help:).. please let me know if u get the answer.. Thanks a lot brother

Comment: This will grab all the text fields in the view, which isn't an ideal solution, and requires that they be direct subviews.  It is possible to recurse over subviews, or scan the scrollView directly - but again, not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

if your `doneEditing:` looks like this `doneEditing:(id)sender` then you can say:

```
UITextField *field = (UITextField *)sender;
NSString *myText = field.text;
```

**EDIT:**

To access a UITextField without setting as an instance variable you need to tag it when you create it:

```
[textField setTag:1];
```

then whenever you want to access it you can get it from its parent view by the tag:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [scroller viewWithTag:1];
NSString *myString = myTextField.text;
```

in your case, set the tag to `i+1` for example to have all the textfield with unique tags.

Comment: im using `doneEditing` function to hide keyboard [`[sender resignFirstResponder]`]. i need to call each UITextField value in a button click.

Comment: set that code i wrote inside your `IBAction` method you want.. you need to pass `sender` as an argument if its not already there.

Comment: Ohh k.. Thats a good idea but unfortunately i need to read values of that UITextBox from another IBAction.. not in `doneEditing`.. is there any other way

Comment: how and where are you calling that IBAction? on what event?

Comment: im calling the IBAction on a button click. IBAction named `-(IBAction)saveAndContinue:(id)sender`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *value = sender.text;
```

If inside an IBAction, of course.

Which ignores that there is a set of text fields, and a single button action.

The simplest solution to the overall problem would be to store a set (or array) of text fields in an instance variable, and iterate over that set in the button action.  But that is a rather coarse approach; it is probably better to use the text field delegate method and store text values directly in an array, using the button to trigger the save.

In addition, Apple HIG would tell you that you should update your data model as the text fields are edited, rather than use a "Save" button - which is poor UX design - unless, of course, the values of individual fields can interact.

Comment: here sender is a UIRoundRectButton. So can u please tell me how can i use `sender.text`?? i need to read values of that UITextBox from an IBAction.. is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

implement the IBAction function like the following:

```
-(IBAction) doneEditing:(UITextField*)sender
{
    NSString * val = sender.text;

}
```

try using the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) , i think its better for your case.

add each UITextField a Tag and by that you will recognise the UITextField.

Comment: No i use `doneEditing` to hide keyboard.. I need to read the values of UITextField on another IBAction (Its a button click)

Comment: use the same function to hide to keyboard and receiving the data. [sender resignFirstResponder]; if you want to recognise the sender you should add tag to each uitextfield