# objective-C : get individual strings for textfields created programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

After going through the solution for [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552322/how-can-i-read-uitextfield-value-in-an-ibaction-im-creating-uitextfield-progra), I get the output in the log when i print the mutableArray as shown below.

```
*Date Project name :* Save button : (
    Def
)
```

where 'Def' is the text entered in the textfield created dynamically. I want to extract 'Def'and display in log on save button click. Here's the code

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    for(UITextField *field in self.scroll.subviews)
    {
        if([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            if([[field text] length] > 0)
            {
                NSMutableArray *mutableTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [mutableTextArray addObject:field.text];
                NSLog(@"Save button : %@", mutableTextArray);
                //NSString *str = [str stringByAppendingString:[mutableTextArray objectAtIndex:0]];
                //[self fetchStrings:str];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void) fetchStrings:(NSString*)enteredString
{
    NSLog("%@", enteredString); //want 'def' to be displayed here
}
```

Comment: `mutableTextArray` should be instance level variable and not local. Then it will be accessible across instance methods.

Comment: @Deepak Thakur  your log is not readable..can you post a screenshot mr.

Comment: i get that by using this NSLog(@"Save button %@", mutableTextArray);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    for(UIView *field in self.scroll.subviews)
    {
        if([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            if(((UITextField *)field).text.length > 0)
            {
                [mutableTextArray addObject:field.text];//mutableTextArray declare this locally in Interfacefile and then initialize the array in viewDidLoad

            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", mutableTextArray); 
}
```

While you create UITextField set the Tag and use like this. I hope it will be work for you

Comment: i think u must have an array inside the innermost if condition. calling method directly is not working.

Comment: @DeepakThakur - (void) fetchStrings:(NSString*)enteredString; declare this in your interface file it will call this method

Comment: @DeepakThakur:Set break point inside this if(((UITextField *)field).text.length > 0) and check the condition satisfies or not?

Comment: it works after removing tag==100. Also, adding break will give me only the first textfields data. I need to handle the remaining ones also..

Comment: i need to change the parameter of fetchStrings from nsstring to nsarray to get all values

Comment: @TamilKing you probably don't want to log the entire `mutableTextArray` on every iteration; maybe move the `NSLog()` outside the `for` loop.