# Validate text fields created dynamically

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfield

I created the text fields after looking at the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552322/how-can-i-read-uitextfield-value-in-an-ibaction-im-creating-uitextfield-progra)

How can I check if the user has entered some text in all the created textfields which are there in the array? If any of the text field is blank, it should return false else return true.

Edit:
Also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681189/objective-c-get-individual-strings-for-textfields-created-programmatically). I get the text field in array. Refer answer in nslog at the end of the answer code.

```
 - (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    mutableTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(field in self.scroll.subviews)
    {
        if([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            if([[field text] length] > 0)
            {
                [mutableTextArray addObject:field.text];
            }

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Save button 2 : %@", mutableTextArray);

    [self fetchStrings:mutableTextArray];

}

- (BOOL) isAllTextFieldsValid {
    for (UITextField *fields in mutableTextArray) {
        // Trim any spaces entered by user.
        NSString *txt = [fields.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if([txt length]==0) {
            //If any of the contained txt fields will have
            //blank text this will return NO.
            return NO;
        }
    }
    //Else if all txt fields have some text entered it them, return YES
    return YES;
}

- (void) fetchStrings:(NSMutableArray *)textArray
{

    NSLog(@"Array string = %@", textArray);
    if(![self isAllTextFieldsValid])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot proceed" message:@"Please answer all questions" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
```

Comment: Doesnt the answer of that question give you what you want? if ([[field text] length] > 0) return YES else return NO

Comment: No, i get the text fields in the array. When one of the text fields is left blank by the user, then it will not return false. I checked in the log. hope you got my point

Comment: please see the edit in my question @Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just initialized array with capacity and compared it with global integer 'i' where 'i' has count of text filds created dynamically. 
It will not work if I don't mention `initWithCapacity:0`. Crazy.

```
mutableTextArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for(field in self.scroll.subviews)
    {
        if([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            if([[field text] length] > 0)
            {
                [mutableTextArray addObject:field.text];
            }

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Save button 2 : %@", mutableTextArray);
    if([mutableTextArray count] != i)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot proceed" message:@"Please answer all questions" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    [self fetchStrings:mutableTextArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of uitextfields just use a for loop and check all the objects in the array for this statement:

```
if ([self.textField.text length] > 0 || [self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""] == FALSE){
//textfield has text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is write a simple function with a `for`-loop to iterate through the array of text fields like this,

```
- (BOOL) isAllTextFieldsValid {
    for (UITextField *field in self.myTextFiledArray) {
        // Trim any spaces entered by user.
        NSString *txt = [field.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if([txt length]==0) {
            //If any of the contained txt fields will have
            //blank text this will return NO.
            return NO;
        }
    }
    //Else if all txt fields have some text entered it them, return YES
    return YES;
}
```

Call this function as,

```
if([object isAllTextFieldsValid]) {
    //All txt fields have text entered
}
else {
    //Show alert to user for filling all text fields,etc.
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: After adding your lines and filling all the text fields, its returning NO.!

Comment: @DeepakThakur Can you please add your actual code in the question?

Comment: @DeepakThakur Where is the code I suggested you? I don't see it being used.

Comment: its still not validating. I copy pasted your bool method having for-each loop and called the it using if([self isAllTextFieldsValid]). it does not return false for blank fields

Comment: @DeepakThakur It is not very complex code so the mistake should be straight forward. Can you debug your code and let me know what is going wrong? Or add the complete code so that I can check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41190/discussion-between-deepak-thakur-and-amar)

Comment: @DeepakThakur Were you able to resolve the issue after our discussion?